# Bootcamp Windows 8.1

Tags: bootcamp, windows, dual-boot

I recently purchased a Macbook Pro and I'd like to run Windows 8.1. I purchased Windows 8.1 online and got a downloadable version. I now tried to run the bootcamp assistant and was asked to insert a CD which I obviously do not have. Is it possible to install it based on my exe-file I got from Microsoft?

Comment: Reminds me of when I bought my first Mac and purchased Windows Vista with office in case I would mis something; I didn't and never used it. May I ask why you want Windows on it? Maybe there is no need. You need a bootable file or disk anyway, this sounds more like a upgrade file for Windows 8.0.

Comment: Good point. I am study econometrics and there is a few programms that are only supported by windows. Plus, i hate numbers/mac excel...

Comment: Yeah, if you are a power user of Excel you definitely want the Windows version.

Comment: What is the model identifier of your Macbook Pro? Or, at least the year and screen type. The procedure to install windows depends on this information. Also, what is the full name of the exe-file. I assume you purchased the 64 bit version of windows. What version of OS X are you currently running?

Answer (score 1):

The downloadable version of Windows 8.1 is upgrade only, not full install, the one with the EXE is for upgrading from Windows 7 or 8... the key being from Windows 8 here..

Simple solution, if a little bodgy...

Download the Windows 8 demo here: http://www.soft-zilla.com/2013/01/windows-8-iso-download.html​

Then upgrade to 8.1 from that using our EXE file.